# Comment s'adresser à une femme dont l'état civil est inconnu ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, politesse, société

Doit-on utiliser *madame*, *mademoiselle*, ou autre chose ?

Answer (score 28):

Selon la [nouvelle règle](http://circulaire.legifrance.gouv.fr/pdf/2012/02/cir_34682.pdf) (circulaire de 2012), le terme *mademoiselle* ne doit plus être utilisé dans les documents administratifs.

---

<sub>*(Translated April 17, 2017)*</sub>

According to the [new rule](http://circulaire.legifrance.gouv.fr/pdf/2012/02/cir_34682.pdf) (2012 memorandum), the term "mademoiselle" should no longer be used in administrative documents.

Comment: Je ne suis pas dans les destinataires de cette lettre, je ne me sens pas concerné. Plus sérieusement, je serais d'accord si l'OP déclarait écrire un formulaire administratif, mais en l'occurence, je ne crois pas, donc cette règle administrative ne doit pas le concerner.

Comment: Et dans ce cas ce n'est pas l'administration qui est en avance sur les moeurs, mais elle ratrappe l'usage populaire qui se rend bien compte que d'insister sur le status marital des femmes flotte entre malpoli et insultant.  Le fait que certaines s'accrochent encore au mademoiselle desuet ne change rien au mouvement general.

Comment: Dans ce cas, pourquoi évoquer la règle administrative ? La langue est un répertoire de nuances, tant que l'on sait y regarder, que l'on pense à ce que l'on dit et à la façon dont cela va être reçu, il n'y a pas de raison d'interdire d'employer un terme pour des raisons morales. L'argot n'est pas interdit : la distinction non plus, si tant est que la façon dont on reçoit un message puisse épuiser les intentions de son auteur.

Answer (score 26):

Dans le soupçon qu'elle puisse être mariée, ou en âge de l'être (avec toute l'appréciation du monde dans ce jugement), *Madame*, et dans le soupçon contraire, *Mademoiselle*.

Sans le droit à l'erreur, *Madame* est plus formel et sera toujours correct.

---

If you suspect that she might be married (based on her age, per your best judgement), "*Madame*", and if you expect her not to be, "*Mademoiselle*".

If there is no room for error, "*Madame*" is more formal and will always be okay.

Comment: L'Administration française à supprimé Mademoiselle de ses formulaires : https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/actualites/002616

Comment: Par chance, l'administration n'est pas l'Académie, et ses décisions ont peu d'importance pour la langue commune.

Comment: Les décisions de l'Académie n'ont guère plus d'effets sur la langue courante que celles de l'administration; elle se contente d'acter les évolutions en prenant suffisamment son temps pour éviter les effets de mode.

Comment: @Unfrancophone. Je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord. Les décisions de l'académie n'ont pas d'impact rapide (éventuellement sur des dictionnaires, mais ceux-ci ont leur propre ligne éditoriale). En revanche, les tournures de l'administration rentrent petit à petit dans les moeurs par l'effet de répétition (comme la télévision).

Answer (score 11):

Dans le domaine formel, la règle s'établit sur le modèle de la [règle donnée par M42](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4540/79). Je pense que c'est lui qui devrait avoir *Bonne réponse* :-) À partir du moment où toute l'administration française suit cette règle, il peut être difficile d'y déroger, même si on n'est pas destinataire...

En situation informelle, il n'est pas très facile d'être sûr d'être poli, car il n'y [a pas consensus](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mademoiselle#Remise_en_question_de_la_distinction_Madame_.2F_Mademoiselle).

Je suis souvent en contact, de façon informelle et ponctuelle, avec des jeunes femmes que je ne connais absolument pas. Je dis toujours *Madame*, car je considère ne pas avoir à établir avec elles une distinction mariée – non mariée.

Mais il arrive régulièrement que l'une d'elle me reprenne et corrige en *Mademoiselle*, particulièrement dans les milieux de culture musulmane. Jusqu'à présent cela s'est toujours bien passé.

---

<sub>*(Translated April 17, 2017)*</sub>

In the formal domain, the rule is based on the model [that Toto described above]. I think his answer ought to be marked right. :) Once the French government begins to follow this rule, it might be hard to deviate from it, even for those who weren't its intended target.

In an informal situation, it's not very easy to be sure one is being polite, because there is [no consensus](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mademoiselle#Remise_en_question_de_la_distinction_Madame_.2F_Mademoiselle). <sup><sub>[Luke's note: I may have to translate that Wikipedia article some day, because [the English version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mademoiselle_(title)) is very stubby!]</sub></sup>

I'm often in informal and limited contact with young women I don't know. I always say "Madame", because I don't consider that I have to make the distinction between being married or unmarried with them.

But it regularly happens that one of them corrects me to "Mademoiselle", particularly in a Muslim cultural milieu. So far this has always gone over well.

Answer (score 9):

Je ne sais pas pour l'Europe, mais au Québec *madame* est la règle en toute circonstance. Au mieux mademoiselle paraît déplacé, au pire horriblement condescendant.

Note: Pour les plus jeunes, le tutoiement est généralement accepté, ce qui élimine le problème. Il se généralise même dans diverses situations (vente au détail, restauration...), mais personnellement je suis vieux jeu (pourtant je n'ai même pas trente ans XD) et je déteste qu'un(e) vendeur(-euse) ou un(e) serveur(-euse) me tutoie.

---

<sub>*(Translated April 17, 2017)*</sub>

I don't know about Europe, but in Québec "madame" is the rule in every circumstance. In the best of cases, "mademoiselle" seems out of place, and in the worst, terribly condescending.

Note: For the youngest girls, it's generally acceptable to use the *tu* form, which eliminates the problem. This holds true in diverse situations (retail, restaurants...), but personally I'm old-fashioned (even though I'm not even 30 years old XD) and I hate it when a salesperson or waiter uses the *tu* form with me.

Answer (score 4):

En politesse française traditionnelle, le terme *Madame* (tout court) est toujours approprié. Si la personne porte un titre, une charge ou une fonction, de nos jours on l'ajoutera, et on dira par exemple *Madame la présidente* au juge qui préside un tribunal.

Comme l'explique [Istao](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4545/3082), si une personne insiste pour l'usage de *Mademoiselle*, il lui suffit alors de le préciser. Bien sûr, on se tiendra ensuite à ce dernier terme. Un tel dialogue n'a rien d'offensant, c'est même plutôt gentil et convivial.

Dans l'autre sens par contre, cela consisterait une gaffe que d'interpeller une personne par *Mademoiselle* et de se voir inviter à utiliser plutôt *Madame*.

---

<sub>*(Translated April 17, 2017)*</sub>

In the traditional norms of French politeness, the term "Madame" (not followed by a name) is always appropriate. If the person has a title, job title, or rank, this is added these days, and we'll say, for example, "Madame la présidente" to the judge presiding over a court.

As Istao explains [above], if a person insists on "Mademoiselle", they simply have to say so. Naturally, you'll proceed to use that term. Conversations of that type are not at all offensive, but even congenial and friendly.

In the other direction, on the other hand, it would be a gaffe to address a person as "Mademoiselle" and to be invited to use "Madame" instead.

Answer (score 2):

On peut très bien se simplifier la vie en disant tout simplement *bonjour*, c'est alors le ton et le sourire qui l'accompagne qui font le reste.

Toutefois, dans des situations plus solennelles, je n'ajoute Madame que pour les personnes inconnues ayant dépassé l'adolescence ; si elles me sont présentées et que  nous sommes amenés à nous revoir, je demande si je peux alors les appeler par leur prénom.

---

<sub>*(Translated April 17, 2017)*</sub>

It's always entirely possible to make life simpler by just saying "hello", and let your tone of voice and smile do the rest.

That said, in more formal situations, I never add "Madame" except for people I'm not acquainted with who are past adolescence; if they're introduced to me and we end up meeting each other a second time, then I ask whether I can call them by their first name.

Comment: Imaginez une seconde que vous êtes au Poste (de police), vous pouvez tentez un "bonjour" a l'agent fonction publique, mais un "Excusez moi Madame" reste plus indiqué.

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer mon second § ne correspond-il pas à la situation avec bonjour?... et ensuite "Pourriez-vous m'aider/m'indiquer..." selon ce qui vous amène dans ce lieu. Pourquoi s'excuser de poser une question à quelqu'un dont le travail est d'accueillir le  public?

Comment: Votre second paragraphe s'intéresse à des situations solennelles, celle que je suggérais était plutôt cocasse (de déclaration de perte à garde à vue… je laisse libre cours à votre imagination). Il est fréquent que l'on (public) ait l'impression de "déranger" lorsque l'on demande quelque chose à un fonctionnaire, même dont le rôle est d'accueillir le public, aussi est-il de bon ton de s'excuser. Par ailleurs "excusez-moi" est une locution qui dans ce sens ne veut qu'attirer l'attention. Comme dans "Excusez-moi, où est […]" qui existe aussi en anglais: " "Excuse me, where is[…]"

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer - Dans ces situations, c'est courant, mais il est plus habile de dire "S'il vous plaît Madame/Monsieur" pour marquer le respect du à une personne qui a la capacité de vous poser des problèmes. S'excuser est déjà plaider coupable, se positionner en perturbateur... solliciter le bon vouloir du roi de la situation de bien vouloir porter un moment son insigne attention sur votre misérable cas... ne fonctionne pas toujours parfaitement, mais engage une discussion apaisée... à condition que vous le soyez vous-même.

Comment: Votre point de vu est Intéressant. Par jeu, je défendrais le contraire: "s'il vous plaît" vous place en position diminuée, vous êtes tributaire du bon vouloir du "Monsieur" ou de la "Madame". Excusez-moi fait irruption de façon presque péremptoire, tout en respectant l'autre qui doit s'interrompre (même si c'est de sa rêverie :-).

Comment: @EmmanuelGleizer - Eh oui, tout est une question d'oralité, d'intonation, de présence ou d'effacement, de rôle social, de ces mille choses qui font que l'on rencontre des gens ou que l'on s'y heurte... le mot écrit est un mot mort, le raviver, ne serait-ce que par la lecture est périlleux... ou théâtrale !

Answer (score 1):

C'est *Madame*. *Mademoiselle* est une vieille tradition qui n'a pas valeur légale , alors que les administrations reconnaissent *Madame* comme le titre de tout individu de sexe féminin de 0 à 178 ans. Il peut arriver que certaines se vexent pour des raisons narcissiques de type « oh j'ai quand même pas une tête de Madame », mais il serait complètement inconvenant de faire de la règle « les femmes sont obsédées par leur physique », le critère de choix pour labelliser une femme. *Madame* permet d'éviter cette question du « je te trouve vieille ou jeune », « vierge ou mariée », « tu as 50 ans mais je veux te flatter ». Quand on y réfléchit bien on voit à quel point la question *madame* ou *mademoiselle* est problématique, notamment en entretien d'embauche.

Answer (score 0):

En Allemagne aussi, le mot **Fräulein** (i.e. mademoiselle) est considéré comme politiquement incorrect. Dans la plupart des fichiers administratifs que j'ai remplis en France, le mot Mademoiselle ne se rencontre plus. Il n'y que deux options ; soit M. (Monsieur), soit Mme (Madame). Cependant, dans quelque cas (très rares) il y a aussi la troisième option Mlle (Mademoiselle).