# French equivalent to Ms

Tags: prénoms, titres

Is there an equivalent in French to the English title "MS"? It's a title for a woman who does not want or need to be identified as married "MRS" or not married "MISS". "MS" is relatively common in English-speaking countries.

Comment: Just use **Madame** / **Mme**. It no longer presumes whether a woman is married or not in modern French. Mademoiselle is obsolete and even prohibited in official forms and letters (in France at least). See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25494/what-is-the-equivalent-to-ms-in-french-language?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment52087_25494

Comment: By the way, you are welcome to ask in English or in French here. No problem.

Comment: It is a duplicate.... but I guess the title of the original question is difficult to find for anglophones.

Comment: @XouDo Yes, that's a reason why duplicate stay searchable and viewable by visitors.